# Where would I put an initial signup screen for new users?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to program a initial start up for new users, simply for them to input their initial Username, Email, possibly a password, and [maybe a login through Patreon if this other StackOverview question works out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71248647/linking-patreon-api-with-a-flutter-application). However, I have been having issues figuring out how to make it work. The code I have currently have is a pretty basic home screen and the main.dart file that launches it. I don't know in which file or how to code a screen that would only launch if the user has visited for the first time or hasn't submitted the proper information yet.

I will happily program and decorate another startup/new user screen, but I just need to know where to implement the code when launching it? Would I add it to the main.dart that launches the home screen or on the home.dart file?

Thanks for your help!

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:bit/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:bit/saved_data.dart';
import 'package:bit/themes.dart';
import 'package:bit/pages/home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'App',
    themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
    theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
    darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

**home.dart**

```dart
import 'package:bit/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:bit/saved_data.dart';
import 'package:bit/themes.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /* final theme = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? 'Dark Theme'
        : 'Light Theme'; */

    var scaffold = Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bible Info & Tech'),
      ),
// Body Home Page Beginning
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),
              child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  Visibility( //visible: ,
                  child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 6),
                    child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(155, 205, 255, 0.8),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Welcome!!!',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),)),
                  Visibility( //visible: ,
                  child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 6),
                    child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(155, 205, 255, 0.8),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('My Classroom',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),)),
                  Visibility( //visible: ,
                  child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 6),
                    child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(155, 205, 255, 0.8),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Current Lesson',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 0, 6, 0),
                        child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                          //value: _lessonprogress,
                        ),),

                        Text('Current Personal Lesson',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),)),
                  Visibility( //visible: ,
                  child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 6),
                    child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(155, 205, 255, 0.8),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text('Awards',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),)),
                ],
              )))),
// Body Home Page End
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Drawer Beginning
        child: ListView(
          children: [
// Drawer Header
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        foregroundImage:
                            AssetImage('assets/images/Untitled_Artwork.png'),
                        radius: 55.0,
                      )),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: FutureBuilder<SettingsModal>(
                        future: PreferencesService.getSettings(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                            return Text(
                              snapshot.data!.username,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                        },
                      )),
                  const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(1, 0.3),
                      child: Text(
                        'Student',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
// Drawer List            
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Settings'),
              subtitle: const Text('Account Info & Settings'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()),
                );
              },
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
            ),
            /* ListTile(
              title: const Text('Test'),
              subtitle: const Text('Testing Page'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Test1()),
                );
              },
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
            ),*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
// Drawer End
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BIT',
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
      home: scaffold,
    );
  }
}

// Settings Page & Account Information
class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  Settings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Settings> createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  final _preferencesService = PreferencesService();
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateFields();
  }

  void _populateFields() async {
    final settings = await PreferencesService.getSettings();
    setState(() {
      _usernameController.text = settings.username;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? 'Dark Theme'
        : 'Light Theme';

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
              'Settings'), /* actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                _saveSettings;
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
              tooltip: 'Save Settings')
        ] */
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                // Account
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 0, 0),
                      child: Text('Account Information',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ))),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 6),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _usernameController,
                      inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15)],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Username',
                        labelText: 'Username',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 6),
                    child: TextField(
                      // controller: _usernameController,
                      // inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15)],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'email@outlook.com',
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  // App Settings
                  children: [
                    // SwitchListTile(value: DarkMode, onChanged: Light => Dark => Light)
                    // ChangeThemeButtonWidget(),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: _saveSettings,
                      child: const Text('Save Settings'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }

  void _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = SettingsModal(
      username: _usernameController.text,
    );

    print(newSettings);
    print(_usernameController.text);
    _preferencesService.saveSettings(newSettings);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a `Wrapper class` and a `Welcome Screen`. When the user first started using the app. `Welcome Screen`will pop up with two buttons. One of them will navigate to the `Login` and the other one will navigate to `SingUp`. Also, you need to create a boolean that will test the user if he/she is already signed in such that `isSignedIn`. Initially, it will be `false`. When the user signed up or signed in then it will be set to `true` and save this variable in the `shared preferences`. Every time, when the user starts the application you need to check this condition. If `isSignedIn` is `true` then navigate to the `Home Screen`. If it is `false` then navigate to the `Welcome Screen`.Consider the following diagram.

[image]

If you are planning to use Firebase for authentication. There is another method you can do to check whether the user is logged in or not in your `MaterialApp` without using the `Wrapper` class. FirebaseAuth returns the current user with the following method. To do that, you need to also consider `state management` in your project.

```
initialRoute:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null ? '/home' : '/welcome',
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't quite get your issue but as I understand, I advice that below code,so you can controll check new user by this approach
firstly, set a bool by the sharedPreferences package

```
TextButton get isNewUserButton=> TextButton(onPressed: ()async{
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('isNewUser',true);
}, child: const Text("Get Started"));
```

then,

```
void main()async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final showHomePage = prefs.getBool('isNewUser') ?? false;
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'App',
    themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
    theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
    darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
    home: showHomePage ? MyApp() : NewUserSignPage ,
  ));
}
```

if user sign out you can use this code

```
TextButton get signOutButton=> TextButton(onPressed: ()async{
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('isNewUser',false);
}, child: const Text("Sign Out"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use named routing. In your MaterialApp, you can set a boolean whether if the user is logged in or not.Such that;

```
 initialRoute: isUserLoggedIn == null ? '/login-screen' : '/home-screen';
```